# Is resultant java.time code has more code statements compared to equivalent Calendar code

Tags: java, java-time, java.util.calendar

Recently, I try to port one of our old code base, from `Calendar` to `java.time`, as we need quite a number of arithmetic functionalities, which is only found in `java.time`.

If we use `Calendar` in our current code base, we need to perform a lot of conversion back-and-forth (From `Calendar` to `Instant`, From `Instant` back to `Calendar`), in the middle of our code.

**To avoid such cumbersome conversion, we decide to eliminate usage of `Calendar`, and port them to equivalent `java.time` code.**

I'm a bit skeptical on my port. As compared with Calendar code, it seems to

- Create more temporary object instances within the while loop.
- Requires more code statements.

### Calendar code

```
// reminderCal is Calendar object.

long startTimestamp = getStartTimestamp();
reminderCal.setTimeInMillis(startTimestamp);

while (startTimestamp <= maxTimestamp) {
    resultList.add(startTimestamp);

    reminderCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    startTimestamp = reminderCal.getTimeInMillis();
}

return resultList;
```

### java.time code

```
// Epoch timestamp loopTs as initial input.

long startTimestamp = getStartTimestamp();
final ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();

while (startTimestamp <= maxTimestamp) {
    resultList.add(startTimestamp);

    // More code, more temporary instances required compared
    // with Calendar's version. Not sure we're doing the right
    // way.
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(startTimestamp);
    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId);
    time = time.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

    startTimestamp = time.atZone(zoneId).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
}

return resultList;
```

---

For the above code, I was wondering, are we doing the port correctly and optimized? Is there any room we can improve in our `java.time`'s port?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with [`Duration.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-)?

Comment: Sorry. I don't get your point. How are we going to apply `Duration.between` for above code example?

Comment: I don't know, since I have zero context to all the extra variables in your code, but since you state you want to *"compute number of months between 2 dates"*, then `Duration.between` would be the obvious choice for the most direct solution to "that" problem

Comment: Sorry. My question isn't clear. I updated my question for better clarification, to give a better context regarding our porting.

Comment: Okay, but what is the importance of `loopTs` and `maxTs`?  Could you simply add `maxTs` to an `Instant` of `loopTs`, which will give two anchor points and use something like `ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(now, then)` (okay `Duration` doesn't have `toMonths`, my bad ) are all the "other" variables of importance? I get it down to about 5 lines without the need to involve the loops

Comment: I gave a better variable naming to the code sample, hopefully it will yields better understanding. Our purpose is to generate a list of valid timestamps in between [startTimestamp, maxTimestamp]. Hence, a while loop is required.

Comment: While I think [the answer by JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52982485/5772882) has addressed your concrete code example nicely, more generally you can find examples either way: some get longer, some get shorter. In my experience, the examples where the `Calendar` code is longer, it’s because code using `Calendar` tends to be rather wordy. In the case where the `java.time` code is longer, it’s because `java.time` requires you to state some things explicitly that were left to defaults before, which in turns ensures that your code more fully expresses your intentions, so it is an advantage.

Comment: Or in brief: Your decision to eliminate usage of `Calendar` is a good one. Once you learn to use java.time the best way I’m convinced that you will be happy about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want date manipulations between times in a given time zone, you shouldn't use milliseconds nor LocalDateTime, but ZonedDateTime. And I would argue that your List should contain Instants instead of longs, but let's keep it that way for now:

```
long startTimestamp = getStartTimestamp();
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();

ZonedDateTime maxDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(maxTimestamp).atZone(zoneId);
ZonedDateTime loopDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(loopTs).atZone(zoneId);

while (!loopDateTime.isAfter(maxDateTime)) {
    tsList.add(loopDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    loopDateTime = loopDateTime.plusDays(1);
}
```

This is more concise, but also more readable. And all the `Instant.ofEpochMilli()` and `toEpochMilli()` calls wouldn't be needed if you wroked with Instants instead of longs.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I'm looking for. We didn't use `Instant`, as our entire data structure is built upon primitive type. We try not to tied to selected library - Like `Calendar` or `java.time`'s.